# FluentValidation Must rule affected by When condition that follows another Must rule

Tags: asp.net-mvc, conditional-statements, fluentvalidation

I've got this fluent validation rule:

```
    RuleForEach(tvm => tvm.Task.Executors).Cascade(CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure).Must((tvm, exec) => { return exec.Deadline.HasValue ? exec.Deadline.Value.Date >= DateTime.Now.Date : true; }).
        When(tvm=>!tvm.Task.Instructed).
        WithMessage("Deadline can't be earlier than today").
        Must((tvm,exec)=>{ return exec.Deadline.HasValue ? exec.Deadline.Value.Date >= tvm.Task.InstructDate.Value.Date : true; }).
        When(tvm=>tvm.Task.Instructed).
        WithMessage("Deadline can't be earlier than the instructed date").
        Must((tvm, exec) => { return exec.InstructionId == (int)Instructions.TakeOwnership ? exec.Deadline != null : true; }).
        WithMessage("Enter deadline");
```

As you can see, there are 3 Must rules. The first 2 are tied to When condition. 
The problem I have is, the second When condition affects the first Must rule. For example, if `tvm.Task.Instructed` is false, and `Deadline` entered is `2016-06-22` (and taking into account that the current date is 2016-06-23) I would expect to receieve `Deadline can't be earlier than today` message. But I don't get that message because the second When checks if `tvm.Task.Instructed` is true and returns false. So it seems When condition affects not only the rule it follows. I would really want to write these rules fluently n one line. Is that possible or I don't have any choice other than defining them separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, by default, the `When` conditions apply to all validators.

See the source code of the `When` extension method, you've got a parameter with this default value.

```
public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, TProperty> Unless<T, TProperty>(this IRuleBuilderOptions<T, TProperty> rule, Func<T, bool> predicate, ApplyConditionTo applyConditionTo = ApplyConditionTo.AllValidators) {
            predicate.Guard("A predicate must be specified when calling Unless");
            return rule.When(x => !predicate(x), applyConditionTo);
        }
```

So change your `When`, adding `ApplyConditionTo.CurrentValidator`

So this should be ok (tested with some sample datas)

```
RuleForEach(tvm => tvm.Task.Executors).
        Cascade(CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure).
        Must((tvm, exec) => { return exec.Deadline.HasValue ? exec.Deadline.Value.Date >= DateTime.Now.Date : true; }).
        When(tvm=>!tvm.Task.Instructed, ApplyConditionTo.CurrentValidator).
        WithMessage("Deadline can't be earlier than today").
        Must((tvm,exec)=>{ return exec.Deadline.HasValue ? exec.Deadline.Value.Date >= tvm.Task.InstructDate.Value.Date : true; }).
        When(tvm=>tvm.Task.Instructed, ApplyConditionTo.CurrentValidator).
        WithMessage("Deadline can't be earlier than the instructed date").
        Must((tvm, exec) => { return exec.InstructionId == (int)Instructions.TakeOwnership ? exec.Deadline != null : true; }).
        WithMessage("Enter deadline");
```